# jQuery: Issue with passing variable to function

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables

I am using the select2 plugin which allows me to set a default value for a multiple select as follows:

```
$('#myID').select2('val', ['val1','val2','val3',...]);
```

This works fine so far but when I try to use a variable instead of hard-coding the different vals then it fails so I guess I am passing the variable the wrong way. 
Can someone here help me with this ?

I tried:

```
var myVar = "['val1','val2','val3']";
$('#myID').select2('val', myVar);
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Why did you add extra quotes around the value of `myVar`? That's a change from your original code, after which it stopped working. So what is likely to be the reason?

Comment: Like Jon said, you need to pass array, not string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unquoting the array

```
var myVar = ['val1','val2','val3'];
$('#myID').select2('val', myVar);
```